# Need to further shorten easy urls

Tags: php, zend-framework, url-rewriting

I'm using the zend framework and have started setting up really easy urls. I'm aware of using a router to redirect basedupon urls to appropirate controllers and actions. However I woudl like to take it to another step.

Currently I have a controller Users with an action View. It takes a variable ID. SO the end link looks like this:

```
mysite.com/users/view/id/123
```

using a router code as below I can shorten this to

mysite.com/users/view/123

```
$router = new Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite();
$router->addRoute(
        'person',
        new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('users/view/:id', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view'))
    );
```

However I want to be able to reduce it even further to:

```
mysite.com/users/123
```

Is this even possible or am I asking too much here?

Comment: @diEcho, actually no. This is easily done through Zend and is supposed to be handled by the framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is this route

```
$routes['users'] = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
  'users/:id',
   array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view', 'id' => null)
);
```

**NOTE**  Keep in mind however, that all your other actions inside Users will not be accessible with this in place *unless* you modify the routes again.

Comment: I have a few doubts about my note, can't test it out at the moment though!